# Class inheritance with specific CSS naming

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I can't really remember *why* this structure within CSS is used?:

`h2.class-name`

Seems that you could just write out `.class-name` and just give that the class for the `h2`:

```
<h2 class="class-name">Title thing</h2>
```

Unless the reason for it is if you cannot edit the HTML. So this would be it, right?:

```
<div class="class-name">
  <h2>Title thing</h2>
</div>
```

I guess I'm just "fuzzy" on what the reasoning would be for that particualr CSS structure.

Comment: There are plenty of uses so this question may be a bit broad by nature. In any event, here's an example... I have a page with active and inactive elements. I determine which elements are active by applying the class `active` in javascript, *but* I want active `div`s to look different than active `h2`s. I'd use `h2.active` and `div.active` to achieve element-specific styling, without requiring me to put a specific class on every element.

Answer (score 2):

`h2.class-name` means, select all the `<h2>` elements that have the class `'class-name'`, consider the following:

```css
p.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

h2.red {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p class="red">
  RED PARAGRAPH
</p>

<h2 class="red">RED HEADING 2</h2>
```

Notice that both the `<p>` and the `<h2>` have the class `'red'`, but its implementation is different for each element, so if a `<p>` has the class `'red'`, style it this way, and if an `<h2>` has the class `'red'` style it that way.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of reasons someone *might* use that construct. The ones that spring to mind are:

- To distinguish between members of the `class-name` class that are `h2` elements and members of it which are some other kind of element.
- To control [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) as `h2.class-name` is more specific than `.class-name`.
- To make it clear to people reading the CSS what elements that class is supposed to be applied to

---

> Unless the reason for it is if you cannot edit the HTML. So this would be it, right?:

No. That would require the use of the child or descendant combinators.

```
.class-name h2 {}
```